# How to run post in python for multiple categories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I am having a Python script that pulls data from a third party API.

Below is the part of code that runs the post command on the API.

```
data = json.dumps({"filters": ["(headline:coronavirus OR summary:coronavirus OR headline:covid-19 OR summary:covid-19) AND categories:164"], "sort_by":"created_at", "size":5000})

type(data)

r = requests.post(url = api_endpoint, data = data).json()
```

In above filters the "categories" number depicts city code for example 164 belongs to Atlanta. I have total 50 cities with different category numbers to run.

Currently I am running line of code  50 times by changing the category number to each city. Is there a better way to run this in one script run instead of 50 times?

That category number is not a serial numbers, each city has been assigned random numbers.

Comment: how you get `id` of cities? do you need to run whole `id` list or specific `id's` in some cases?

Comment: No the API has id assigned to each city. 163- Atlanta 164- Austin and so on

Comment: `TinNguyen` answer is what you need?

Comment: are you sure there is not a get endpoint to retrieve all the city ids somewhere else in the API? (so you do not have to write out all the numbers)

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = [164, 50, 69]

for number in numbers:

  data = json.dumps({"filters": ["(headline:coronavirus OR summary:coronavirus OR headline:covid-19 OR summary:covid-19) AND categories:{number}".format(number=number)], "sort_by":"created_at", "size":5000})

  r = requests.post(url = api_endpoint, data = data).json()
```

However instead of `AND categories:164` you might be able to write:

`AND (categories:164 OR categories: 50 OR categories: 69)`

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

```
# put all your categories into a list called categories: [164, 203, ..]
for category in categories:
    payload = {"filters": ["(headline:coronavirus OR summary:coronavirus OR 
              headline:covid-19 OR summary:covid-19) AND categories: 
              {}".format(category)], "sort_by":"created_at", "size":5000}
    r = requests.post(url = api_endpoint, data = json.dumps(data)).json()
```